# converting RGB values into HTML color code?

Tags: jquery, html, colors

How can I convert RGB values into HTML code?

For example, using values like this:

```
red:0
blue:0
green:0
html color code = #000000
```

Is there any formula for converting it?

Comment: First google result: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/12/29/convert-rgb-to-hex.aspx

Comment: Do your `red`, `green`, and `blue` value range from 0-1 or 0-255?

Comment: @citizen conn - was about to post the very same link :)

Comment: yes the value range from 0 - 255

Comment: Do you specifically need the hex code? You can actually just use the rgb values in CSS e.g. `color: rgb(0,0,0);`

Comment: Yes I do unless HTML can understand rgb values..I think it can't?

Comment: I have given you an example of the proper syntax in the comment above, and if you look at my answer below you will see a live example. rgb values can be used to style html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to convert each component value to its corresponding hex representation, and concatenate them into a string, like:

```
function colorCode(red, green, blue) {
   red = normalize(red);
   green = normalize(green);
   blue = normalize(blue);

   return '#' + pad(red.toString(16)) + pad(green.toString(16)) + pad(blue.toString(16)); 
}

function pad(string) {
    return string.length > 1 ? string.toUpperCase() : "0" + string.toUpperCase();
}

function normalize(color) {
    return (color < 1.0 && color > 0.0) ? Math.floor(color * 255) : color;
}
```

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/5TdXJ/2

Answer (score 4):

If you don't specifically need to use the hex value (html colour code) you can actually just use the rgb values you already have. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/DdFg8/1/

```
color: rgb(0,0,0); /* black */

color: rgb(255,255,255); /* white */
```

Answer (score 0):

the HTML representation is just a hex represntation of the rgb values

```
python -c 'print "%x" % (255)'  # prints ff
```

Answer (score 0):

If you search "**Convert RGB to Hex**" on Google you will see a tons of online converter. What HTML (that # sign string) is a Hex presentation of color, where the first two hex digit represents Red, the middle two digit represents Green and the last two digit represent Blue.